# How can I add my app shortcuts to the System Preferences Keyboard Pane?

Tags: macos, cocoa

I have a Cocoa (non-document) application where I registered HotKeys through the EventRegisterHotKey() function.  All is working well.  Is there a way to "install" my app's global shortcuts into the System Preferences Keyboard pane (System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts)?

Comment: Please paste your code here so that will get to know what are you tried?

Comment: I currently don't have any code.  I can't find any APIs that allow me to setup some shortcuts in System Preferences and I'm wondering if anyone knows how to do this.